Pyspark computation time increases with less data
I'm posed with a problem where i have to iterate the same computations on each row of data until they converge. My train of thought was to remove the converged rows after each iteration so the computation time decreases on the next iteration.
Then i notice the computation increases with each iteration.
I'm somewhat new to pyspark and am currently attempting to rewrite my code using F.when() instead, but i feel there is a lesson to be learned here in any case.
I made a small demo below to illustrate the problem:
import time
def create_dummy_df(size=10000):
    data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(size, 6))

    rows = [(float(a), float(b), float(c), float(d), float(e), float(f)) for a,b,c,d,e,f in data]

    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])

def doComputation(df):
    """Simulate heavy polynomial calculations with increased complexity"""
    df = df.withColumn("res_a", F.pow(F.col("a"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("res_b", F.pow(F.col("b"), 3))
    df = df.withColumn("res_c", F.pow(F.col("c"), 4))
    df = df.withColumn("res_d", F.pow(F.col("a") + F.col("b"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("res_e", F.pow(F.col("b") + F.col("c"), 3))
    df = df.withColumn("res_f", F.pow(F.col("c") + F.col("a"), 4))
    df = df.withColumn("output", F.col("res_a") + F.col("res_b") + F.col("res_c") + F.col("res_d") + F.col("res_e") + F.col("res_f"))
    df = df.withColumn("converged", F.col("output") > 5)
    # Increase a, b, c by 0.01 so more will converge in next iteration
    df = df.withColumn("a", F.col("a") + 0.01).withColumn("b", F.col("b") + 0.01).withColumn("c", F.col("c") + 0.01)
    return df

def testFunc(df, maxIter = 40):
    total_rows = df.count()
    converged_rows = []
    for i in range(maxIter):
        t = time.time()
        df = doComputation(df)
        
        # Identify converged rows
        converged = df.filter(F.col("converged") | F.isnan('output'))
        
        # Remove converged rows from working set
        df = df.filter(~F.col("converged") & ~F.isnan('output'))

        #re-persist dataframe to avoid exploding computation tree on later iterations
        df.unpersist()
        df = df.cache()
        remaining = df.count()
        
        #store converged rows with information on when they converged
        if not converged.isEmpty():
            converged_rows.append(converged.withColumn("converged_iteration", F.lit(i+1)))
                
        print(f"Iteration {i+1}: {total_rows - remaining}/{total_rows} rows converged, iteration time: {time.time()-t:.2f} seconds")    
        if remaining == 0:
            break

    
    t = time.time()
    # merge all converged results
    result_df = converged_rows[0]
    for df_chunk in converged_rows[1:]:
        result_df = result_df.union(df_chunk)

    # merge unconverged results with iteration 999
    if df.count() > 0:
        result_df = result_df.union(df.withColumn("converged_iteration", F.lit(999)))
    print(f'merge time: {time.time()-t:.2f} seconds')
    return result_df

testdf = create_dummy_df()
testFunc(testdf)

Iteration 1: 4350/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.87 seconds
Iteration 2: 4574/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.26 seconds
Iteration 3: 4821/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 0.88 seconds
Iteration 4: 5028/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 0.82 seconds
Iteration 5: 5253/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.03 seconds
Iteration 6: 5509/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.17 seconds
Iteration 7: 5745/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.02 seconds
Iteration 8: 5977/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.24 seconds
Iteration 9: 6196/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.19 seconds
Iteration 10: 6410/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.27 seconds
Iteration 11: 6623/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.41 seconds
Iteration 12: 6829/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.44 seconds
Iteration 13: 6998/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.45 seconds
Iteration 14: 7186/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.08 seconds
Iteration 15: 7354/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.65 seconds
Iteration 16: 7523/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.89 seconds
Iteration 17: 7673/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.03 seconds
Iteration 18: 7852/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.00 seconds
Iteration 19: 7994/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.91 seconds
Iteration 20: 8132/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.05 seconds
Iteration 21: 8261/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.57 seconds
Iteration 22: 8371/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.45 seconds
Iteration 23: 8497/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.14 seconds
Iteration 24: 8612/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.72 seconds
Iteration 25: 8713/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.91 seconds
Iteration 26: 8822/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.02 seconds
Iteration 27: 8945/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.18 seconds
Iteration 28: 9026/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.23 seconds
Iteration 29: 9115/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.63 seconds
Iteration 30: 9202/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.66 seconds
Iteration 31: 9273/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.76 seconds
Iteration 32: 9338/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.49 seconds
Iteration 33: 9412/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.09 seconds
Iteration 34: 9472/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.32 seconds
Iteration 35: 9546/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.67 seconds
Iteration 36: 9590/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.30 seconds
Iteration 37: 9643/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.54 seconds
Iteration 38: 9688/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.93 seconds
Iteration 39: 9732/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 5.67 seconds
Iteration 40: 9769/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 5.72 seconds


Are you using azure databricks?

No, I work with Azure Synapse Analytics

can you print the plan every iteration or at the very end? In general Spark behaves strangely when you create plans in loops. Also have you tried with a few million/billion rows? 10000 may not give you accurate results.


Spark behaves strangely when you create plans (Dataframes) in loops. Uncomment # df.explain() in code below and see the printed plans for each test_type
There are many ways to force execution of each plan created in every step (iteration), before next step starts. See force_plan_execution() in the modified code below. These have evolved over time, e.g. back in the day df.count() used to force plan execution, today (newer spark) it does not.
Usually it's a little a bit of trial an error exercise to find what fits your case best. Note the merge time for each test_type. If you do say 15 iterations then merge of "orig" would be faster merge of "rdd".
"remove the converged rows after each iteration so the computation time decreases on the next iteration" Depending on how your data is partitioned etc, this might not help, or might even make things worse (become an unnecessary overhead). I don't quite understand what you're doing in your code so can't say. But know that you won't be able to take whatever you learn here as a general approach and apply it another experiment (that has a totally different implementation of doComputation() and/or operates on a much larger data set) and expect same behavior. That's why #3.


import time
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


def create_dummy_df(size=10000):
    data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(size, 6))
    rows = [(float(a), float(b), float(c), float(d), float(e), float(f)) for a,b,c,d,e,f in data]
    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
  
def force_plan_execution(df, test_type):
  # 'as_table', 'rdd'
  if test_type == 'as_table':
    df.write.saveAsTable("df_temp_view1", mode="overwrite")
    return spark.read.table("df_temp_view1")
  elif test_type == 'rdd':
    r = df.rdd
    s = df.schema
    return r.toDF(s)
  else:
    return df


def doComputation(df):
    """Simulate heavy polynomial calculations with increased complexity"""
    df = df.withColumn("res_a", F.pow(F.col("a"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("res_b", F.pow(F.col("b"), 3))
    df = df.withColumn("res_c", F.pow(F.col("c"), 4))
    df = df.withColumn("res_d", F.pow(F.col("a") + F.col("b"), 2))
    df = df.withColumn("res_e", F.pow(F.col("b") + F.col("c"), 3))
    df = df.withColumn("res_f", F.pow(F.col("c") + F.col("a"), 4))
    df = df.withColumn("output", F.col("res_a") + F.col("res_b") + F.col("res_c") + F.col("res_d") + F.col("res_e") + F.col("res_f"))
    df = df.withColumn("converged", F.col("output") > 5)
    # Increase a, b, c by 0.01 so more will converge in next iteration
    df = df.withColumn("a", F.col("a") + 0.01).withColumn("b", F.col("b") + 0.01).withColumn("c", F.col("c") + 0.01)
    return df

def testFunc(df, test_type, num_iter = 16):
    total_rows = df.count()
    converged_rows = []
    for i in range(num_iter):
        t = time.time()
        df = doComputation(df)
        df = force_plan_execution(df, test_type)
        # df.explain()
        
        # Identify converged rows
        converged = df.filter(F.col("converged") | F.isnan('output'))
        
        # Remove converged rows from working set
        df = df.filter(~F.col("converged") & ~F.isnan('output'))

        #re-persist dataframe to avoid exploding computation tree on later iterations
        df.unpersist()
        df = df.cache()
        remaining = df.count()
        
        #store converged rows with information on when they converged
        if not converged.isEmpty():
            converged_rows.append(converged.withColumn("converged_iteration", F.lit(i+1)))
        if i % 2 == 1:
          print(f"Iteration {i+1}: {total_rows - remaining}/{total_rows} rows converged, iteration time: {time.time()-t:.2f} seconds")    
        if remaining == 0:
            break

    
    t = time.time()
    # merge all converged results
    result_df = converged_rows[0]
    for df_chunk in converged_rows[1:]:
        result_df = result_df.union(df_chunk)

    # merge unconverged results with iteration 999
    if df.count() > 0:
        result_df = result_df.union(df.withColumn("converged_iteration", F.lit(999)))
    print(f'merge time: {time.time()-t:.2f} seconds')
    return result_df


for test_type in ['rdd', 'orig', 'as_table', ]:
  t = time.time()
  print(f"Start {test_type} {'-'*60}")
  testdf = create_dummy_df()
  testFunc(testdf, test_type)
  print(f"END Total time: {test_type} {time.time()-t:.2f} seconds {'-'*40}")

prints:
Start rdd ------------------------------------------------------------
Iteration 5: 5299/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 0.93 seconds
Iteration 10: 6439/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.31 seconds
Iteration 15: 7358/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.90 seconds
Iteration 20: 8151/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.76 seconds
Iteration 25: 8774/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.83 seconds
Iteration 30: 9232/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 5.07 seconds
merge time: 1.42 seconds
END Total time: rdd 72.91 seconds ----------------------------------------
Start orig ------------------------------------------------------------
Iteration 5: 5283/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 0.45 seconds
Iteration 10: 6364/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 0.84 seconds
Iteration 15: 7344/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 1.40 seconds
Iteration 20: 8099/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 2.01 seconds
Iteration 25: 8726/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.03 seconds
Iteration 30: 9209/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 3.97 seconds
merge time: 5.76 seconds
END Total time: orig 58.26 seconds ----------------------------------------
Start as_table ------------------------------------------------------------
Iteration 5: 5229/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.34 seconds
Iteration 10: 6347/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.46 seconds
Iteration 15: 7296/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.39 seconds
Iteration 20: 8114/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.58 seconds
Iteration 25: 8743/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 4.54 seconds
Iteration 30: 9208/10000 rows converged, iteration time: 5.07 seconds
merge time: 0.18 seconds
END Total time: as_table 139.36 seconds ----------------------------------------

